# What's the difference between a Gaussian and a Lorentzian?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, gaussian

I would like to know the difference between a Gaussian function and a Lorentzian function. In particular, is it right to say that the second one is more peaked (sharper) than the first one that has a more smoothed bell-like shape ? In fact, also [here](https://www.globalsino.com/EM/page2511.html) it tells that *the Lorentzian distribution has a much smaller degree of tailing than Gaussian distribution*. Is it true? Could you prove this with some relationship between the Gaussian FHWM and the Lorentzian FHWM, for example ?

My question comes from the fact that I have to fit two curves obtained by experimental data (the ones of the image that I attach) and I was wondering if fitting the sharper peak with a Lorentzian function and the more bell-like shape curve with a Gaussian fuction would give more precise results of the parameters that I am searching (with respect to the case in which I use for both of them the Gaussian equation).

Actually, I fit the red curve using the Lorentzian equation and the blue one (more smoothed) with a Gassian equation in order to find the X value corresponding to the peaks of the two curves (for instance, for the red curve, I wrote a code in which I put the equation of the Lorentzian and left the parameter, which I am interested in, free so that the fitting gives me its value).[image]

Comment: Can you be more concrete about what you are trying to do?

Comment: Well, the Gaussian and Lorentzian are… two ends of the [Mittag-Leffler function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_function). That's what I can think of.

Comment: @AntoniParellada I tried to be more concrete...

Comment: @ParclyTaxel it does not really help me but I will think better about it, so thank you.

Comment: Thank you. I voted to reopen the question. I had upvoted it initially, but without more details it couldn't be properly answered. Good luck getting help. :-) Are you using R? If so, have you tried `fitdistr()`?

Comment: @AntoniParellada thank you. I am able to do the fit that gives me the result that I want but I wanted only to know if fitting the red curve with a Lorentzian and the blue one with a Gaussian function is a more precise way of working with respect to fitting both of them with a Gaussian, for example. I would like to know if it is a good reasoning from a mathematical point of view.

Comment: Anyway I forgot to answer that yes I am doing with R :)